# Blue Boxes around anchored list items html

Tags: jquery, html, list, hyperlink, border

Look at the images below, I've tried all sorts to get rid of these borders, I've tried every css trick you could think of. Nothing is working, its a Jquery tabbed panel

[image]
[image]

Comment: Posting the HTML markup and relevant javascript in addition to the CSS strategies which have been tried, would be helpful.

Comment: Is that an `a` tag which is focused?

Comment: You have not provided any code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

More than likely, without seeing the code I'd guess that these are  tags...

Therefore, a simple:

```
 border: none;
```

Will suffice in removing the blue borders...